# Why does kendo dropdownlist takes time to load?

Tags: drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

I am having trouble with kendo dropdownlist performance. it takes time to load. I have four dropdownlists in cascade . Is that the reason, too much data and plus cascading?
I am using remote data binding. So the lists are imported from server via sql query. i think its taking more than 10 seconds to load the first cascaded list.
when page is refreshed though the speed is fine. the first loading is the problem 
hope i have added more details

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should try to post as much detail as possible so that people can help answer your question. In this case, unless we know how much data you are loading, and how you are loading it, it will be very hard to help. Also, how long is it taking to load?

Comment: Maybe you could cache the data in the server. Dropdown menus do not usually update so often.